# Why is my ng-repeat directive creating an invalid HTTP request?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

Using Anguar UI-Router, I have the following state configured:

```
angular.module('foos').config(['$stateProvider',
function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.
    state('seeFoos', {
        url: '/foos',
        templateUrl: 'modules/foos/client/views/list-foos.client.view.html',
        controller: 'FoosController',
        resolve: {
          initialData : function(Foos) {
            return Foos.query();
          }
        }
    });
}
]);
```

In my view, I use ng-repeat to load some images by getting the image name from a service.

```
<section>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 top15"
        ng-repeat-start="foo in bar">
        <h4 ng-bind="foo.name"></h4>
        <div class="row">
            <a href="{{foo.link}}"> 
                <img alt="{{foo.name}}" src="modules/foos/client/img/{{foo.imgName}}" class="col-xs-4" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix" ng-if="$index%2==1"></div>
    <div ng-repeat-end=""></div>
</div>
</section>
```

Note that I ensure Foos.query() resolves before the template is loaded. The controller then loads the result to `bar` on the `scope`

```
angular.module('foos').controller('FoosController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Foos', 'initialData',
  function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Foos, initialData) {
    $scope.bar = initialData;
  }
]);
```

Everything works as expected, save for the following extra HTTP GET that returns a 404 error:

```
GET /modules/foos/client/img/%7B%7Bfoo.imgName%7D%7D
```

I don't understand why that request is being generated once I add the `resolve` option on the state configuration.

Comment: Simply use [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) instead of `src`. Also, is `Foos.query()` a `$resource` action, because if it is, your `resolve` needs some alteration

Comment: Ah, didn't know about ng-src, I'll check it out. Yes, Foos.query() is a $resouce action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem can be solved by using `ng-src` instead of `src`. From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)...

> Using Angular markup like `{{hash}}` in a `src` attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text `{{hash}}` until Angular replaces the expression inside `{{hash}}`. The `ngSrc` directive solves this problem.

---

Secondly, your `resolve` function does not wait for the query to complete before completing the state load. This is by design in [`$resource` actions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#usage)...

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.

If you **do** want it to wait, change the `resolve` to

```
resolve: {
  initialData : function(Foos) {
    return Foos.query().$promise;
  }
}
```

---

And finally, you can simply use `ng-if="$odd"` instead of `ng-if="$index%2==1"`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I also appreciate the advice on properly using `$resource`.